# What is the proper mechanism for separating build and test stages in azure-pipelines?

Tags: c++, git, testing, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a toy C++ cmake project with the following azure-pipelines.yml (see [HelloAzure](https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/HelloAzure) for sources).

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
    - master 
variables:
  SOURCE_DIR: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  BUILD_DIR: '$(SOURCE_DIR)/build'
  INSTALL_DIR: '$(SOURCE_DIR)/install'

stages:
  - stage: Build 
    displayName: Build 
    pool: 
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest    
    jobs:
      - job: BuildLinux 
        strategy:
          matrix:
            Release:
              BUILD_TYPE: 'Release'
            Debug:
              BUILD_TYPE: 'Debug'
        steps:
          - script: | 
              echo "mkdir BUILD_DIR $(BUILD_DIR)"
              mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)
              echo "cd build directory "
              cd $(BUILD_DIR)
              echo " Run configure command"
              cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(INSTALL_DIR)/$(BUILD_TYPE) $(SOURCE_DIR)
              echo "running cmake build command"
              cmake --build . --target install --config $(BUILD_TYPE) -j 12 
  - stage: BuildTests
    dependsOn: Build
    displayName: BuildTests 
    jobs: 
      - job: RunCTestLinux 
        steps: 
          - script: |
              cd $(BUILD_DIR)
              ctest
```

Locally I can do the following:

```
# download sources
git clone https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/HelloAzure.git

# build
cd HelloAzure
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install ..
cmake --build . --target install --config Release -j 12

# test
ctest
```

I am trying to reproduce this workflow in azure. It is trivial to do using just one stage, but as soon as I try to run the tests in a "test" stage, [Azure simply re-downloads the sources and tried to run the tests without first having ran the build command](https://dev.azure.com/CWAzureExperiments/AzureExperiments/_build/results?buildId=7&view=logs&j=dfd7719d-74e7-5ac9-a996-f4d803ac04df&t=7efac5b2-1f19-407c-9f5b-9e6617c641bc).

So my question, what is the proper mechanism for separating the build and test stages of a project in azure-pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you may try the following approach：

1 .In **Build** stage, adding a task to publish the build output. For example:

```
steps:
- publish: string # path to a file or folder
  artifact: string # artifact name
  displayName: string  # friendly name to display in the UI
```

2 .In **BuildTests** stage, adding a task to download the build output:

```
steps:
- download: [ current | pipeline resource identifier | none ] # disable automatic download if "none"
  artifact: string ## artifact name, optional; downloads all the available artifacts if not specified
  patterns: string # patterns representing files to include; optional
  displayName: string  # friendly name to display in the UI
```

3 .Nondeployment jobs automatically check out source code. Use the `checkout` keyword to configure or suppress this behavior. In **BuildTests** stage, adding the following step to suppress automatically the source code checked out:

```
steps:
- checkout: none
```